# How to use firebase oauth as a login tool for vps applications.?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, passport.js

Hello all firebase experts,
I just learned about node.js today, and I intend to use firebase oauth as a login tool in my application and install the application on vps, is there a suggestion that the NPM package should be used? or is there a simple example that I can understand?

Answer (score 0):

At server side (Node) you won't need to OAuth but you may need to OAuth as Admin. And for this;

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
});

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("restricted_access/secret_document");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```